# Extract email Password from an Encrypted Backup

Tags: ios, backup

How can I extract email passwords from an encrypted iOS backup stored in iCloud?

Answer (score 1):

Eek this sounds like a bit of a task. First off you will want to download your encrypted backup from iCloud. You can only do this with 3rd party tools that will probably cost you a little money. You can use http://www.eoosoft.com/how-to/download-icloud-backup-to-pc-mac.html to download the backup from iCloud. Then you can use a tool like http://www.iphonebackupextractor.com/ to extract the information you need from the backup.